# React reading from firebase, getting error

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to get data from firebase collection but getting error, can anybody help?
I am getting this error

> Error: Context from react-redux not found. If you are using react-redux v6 a v3.*.* version of react-redux-firebase is required. Please checkout the v3 migration guide:

here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Notifications from './Notifications';
import ProjectList from '../projects/ProjectList';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {firestoreConnect} from 'react-redux-firebase';
import {compose} from 'redux';
import { firebaseConnect, isLoaded, isEmpty } from 'react-redux-firebase'

class Dashboard extends Component {
render() {

return (
  <div className="dashboard container">
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col s12 m6"><ProjectList projects={this.props.projects}></ProjectList></div>
        <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1"><Notifications></Notifications></div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>
{
  console.log(state);
 return ({projects:state.projectReducer.projects})
}
export default compose(firebaseConnect([
'projects'
]), connect(mapStateToProps)) (Dashboard)
```

I have tried this export but same error

```
export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps), firestoreConnect([
{collection:'project'}
])) (Dashboard)
```

here is my package.json

```
{
"name": "myproject",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"firebase": "^5.7.0",
"firedux": "^1.1.0",
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
"react-redux": "^6.0.0",
"react-redux-firebase": "^2.2.5",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "2.1.1",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-firestore": "^0.6.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not ie <= 11",
"not op_mini all"
]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is quite clear, you are using `react-redux-firebase`:`^2.2.5` while you need to use v3, because you are using `react-redux`: `^6.0.0`.

You have to update `react-redux-firebase`

Comment: i used npm install react-redux-firebase redux-firestore to install packages, it should have installed the latest packages. I am new to React, how can i upgrade the package? just update the package.json and save?

Comment: `react-redux-firebase` v3 is still in alpha version, it won't be available when you use npm install. In that case you may need to downgrade react-redux to lastest version to `5.1.1`

Comment: worked, thanx. how can i check what version of react-redux-firebase is compatible with react-redux?

Comment: I think you might check the changelogs or package.json of react-redux-firebase

Answer (score 1):

If you're following along with someone's example and not building a production app, you can just switch to react-redux 5.1.1.

Just change `"react-redux": "^6.0.0",` to `"react-redux": "^5.1.1",` in package.json and run  `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

@kabanny above is quite correct.

If you really want to use the next version of `react-redux-firebase` that supports the context api, then do the following at your own risk.

```
npm install react-redux-firebase@next
```

Also check out the [migration guide](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/docs/v3-migration-guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you did install the packages using `npm`. downgrading to `react-redux-firebase@2.2.5` and `react-redux@5.1.1`  did solve the problem in my case. Something to take note of: In case you face such errors when following someone's tutorials, I recommend you first confirm the version of dependencies they are using. `npm` can land you in trouble.